# Line and Paragraph Spacing in MS Power Automate

Tags: power-automate

I'm exploring Power Automate New Designer and I have a question.

How can I adjust the line and paragraph spacing in the email body? When I use one space after each paragraph in the flow, the actual email shows two spaces. Here are the screenshots of the flow and the email. Any advice would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

I removed all spaces in the flow email body to avoid having more than one space in my actual email. In some cases I need to remove all spaces after paragraph. However, there seems to be a space that won't go away.

Comment: It’ll be the style differences between PA and Outlook, that’s important really. You might find another email client treat it differently again. Your best bet is to fashion up the email in HTML.

Comment: I noticed that the latest update changed the style of PA and Outlook. They used to be consistent, which made sense considering both are Microsoft product. I was hoping that the new version would make PA more intuitive, not less.

Is there any easy way to fix it? HTML seems like bit more hassle for a simple task.

Comment: As an unannounced policy, which Microsoft seems to be practicing for more than three decades at least, of releasing their products with tons of bugs and then use all its customers as unpaid testers to figure-out varieties of bugs, keeping them busy, struggling, wasting their precious time and resource.

Answer (score 0):

I navigated back to classic designer (button in the top right). I had a condition in my flow that generated two different but similar e-mails depending on the result of the condition. One version of the e-mail had somehow been updated (maybe when I tried to make edits) to the "new designer" format. I compared the html code in each e-mail - the new and classic designer formats. The new designer format had paragraph tags ("

" at the beginning and "

" at the end) of each line, whereas the former code had breaks. I solved the problem by going back to classic and reinserting the previous code.